replicate solstorm token claim transaction
i'm trying to programaticaly replicate a token airdrop claim from solstorm. this is a sample transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/3qcobJSjuZ8VZJg4uAmuwwfDDWxDBingKS4cYJS2J8N2bdHJgxY5H7F52TXAF2H2mem7KF3x3V2qYTZ9BoCsLuhn
i want to replace the fee payer/receiving address and token amount.
i tried collecting the sample transaction details
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Connection, PublicKey } = solanaWeb3;

const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

const transactionId = '3qcobJSjuZ8VZJg4uAmuwwfDDWxDBingKS4cYJS2J8N2bdHJgxY5H7F52TXAF2H2mem7KF3x3V2qYTZ9BoCsLuhn';

async function getTransactionDetails() {
    try {
        const transactionDetails = await connection.getParsedTransaction(transactionId);

        if (!transactionDetails) {
            console.error('Transaction not found');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Transaction details:', transactionDetails);

        const {
            blockTime,
            meta: {
                fee,
                logMessages,
                preBalances,
                postBalances,
                preTokenBalances,
                postTokenBalances
            },
            transaction: {
                message: {
                    accountKeys,
                    instructions,
                    recentBlockhash
                },
                signatures
            }
        } = transactionDetails;

        console.log('Block Time:', blockTime);
        console.log('Fee:', fee);
        console.log('Log Messages:', logMessages);
        console.log('Pre Balances:', preBalances);
        console.log('Post Balances:', postBalances);
        console.log('Pre Token Balances:', preTokenBalances);
        console.log('Post Token Balances:', postTokenBalances);
        console.log('Account Keys:', accountKeys.map(key => key.pubkey.toBase58()));
        console.log('Instructions:', instructions);
        console.log('Recent Blockhash:', recentBlockhash);
        console.log('Signatures:', signatures);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving transaction details:', error);
    }
}

getTransactionDetails();

but i have no clue how to generate the new transaction. am I on the right track with getParsedTransaction? or am I missing some details?
sample unsigned transaction:
Program ID:
"ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111"

Data:
[3,64,13,3,0,0,0,0,0]

Program ID:
"ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL"

Accounts:
Solana Account 3
**HpXU7rgf7sjkPBEYH7x6qxkkdRdtWEqNuvkcCiH7U7rC**
Solana Account 3
H7bTHGb5Cvo5fGe5jBDNDPUv8KykQnzyZA3qZ8sH7yxw
11111111111111111111111111111111
TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Data:
[]

Program ID:
"F1N779UttYHZk79iTGFWoYE4ETNZ9MxeZMrf1EFu9b93"

Accounts:
DAUPakfAi1SrK3V3NoCS1h86Z5E5Hj7U2voQLs9LSnNw
Solana Account 3
**8myyQHWVmcce2TjBQ8Z93j7PKkLn6wVEjr6e5drTSD8g**
EZe6ogoMwdyQu91QbfZTi4uagAyyZ1mn8RFh2NZK4QmX
11111111111111111111111111111111
TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Data:
[14,51,68,159,237,78,158,102,0,**184,201,166,99**,0,0,0]

Program ID:
"F1N779UttYHZk79iTGFWoYE4ETNZ9MxeZMrf1EFu9b93"

Accounts:
DAUPakfAi1SrK3V3NoCS1h86Z5E5Hj7U2voQLs9LSnNw
Solana Account 3
**HpXU7rgf7sjkPBEYH7x6qxkkdRdtWEqNuvkcCiH7U7rC**
**8myyQHWVmcce2TjBQ8Z93j7PKkLn6wVEjr6e5drTSD8g**
EZe6ogoMwdyQu91QbfZTi4uagAyyZ1mn8RFh2NZK4QmX
H7bTHGb5Cvo5fGe5jBDNDPUv8KykQnzyZA3qZ8sH7yxw
CAYjpKeiNkNC5jXcexmD2k1wP97UhKW7D864DAVG1gkS
TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Data:
[52,132,126,180,253,191,178,59]

System Program - Transfer
From Account
Solana Account 3
To Account
7GyvakQMLt1EPY8ZH7e5eyDoqJkwcWKmaCt1tp2hQN45
Lamports
**0.010090145** SOL

the only difference between transactions is the data in bold (between **). the first public key is for the associated token account, the second i still don't know how it is calculated, and the 4 byte in the instructions data which i still didn't dig into it

in order to achieve this you have to know how to call their program, meaning having heir IDL. I don't know if they have published it or not. If you don't have access to the IDL, you may be able to do it tying to understand which accounts you need to send in the instruction, and which args, but that's not an easy job (depending on how complex is the instruction)

thanks, as far as i know the IDL is not published. the instruction seems to be simple, i compared some transactions and all what is changed is the 3 addresses (main account, ATA, and i still didn't figure out how the 3rd is calculated) and 4 bytes in the instructions data, i updated the question with the sample unsigned transaction
